Why is the warning "mutable reference to mutable static" triggered for a "static mut u8", but not for the first element in a "static mut [u8; 1]"?
I'm trying to port some old embedded C code to Rust as an exercise to teach myself the language.
I have some static mutable state that's in a location monitored by the simulator for the device, and this is used to send debug output to. Since the memory is never read from my Rust code, I'm using write_volatile to prevent the optimiser from removing all the dead (from Rust's perspective) code.
I've noticed something strange that I can't get my head around, and for some reason it only happens in the 1.79 nightly build used by the AVR template I'm using (nightly-2024-03-22-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu), but not with my normal 1.78 rustc.
This minimal example:
use core::ptr::write_volatile;

static mut X: u8 = 0;
static mut Y: [u8; 1] = [0];

fn main() -> ! {
    loop {
        unsafe {
            write_volatile(&mut X, 0xC);
            write_volatile(&mut Y[0], 0xD);
        }
    }
}

produces the following warning:
warning: creating a mutable reference to mutable static is discouraged
  --> src/main.rs:67:28
   |
67 |             write_volatile(&mut X, 0xC);
   |                            ^^^^^^ mutable reference to mutable static
   |
   = note: for more information, see issue #114447 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114447>
   = note: this will be a hard error in the 2024 edition
   = note: this mutable reference has lifetime `'static`, but if the static gets accessed (read or written) by any other means, or any other reference is created, then any further use of this mutable reference is Undefined Behavior
   = note: `#[warn(static_mut_refs)]` on by default
help: use `addr_of_mut!` instead to create a raw pointer
   |
67 |             write_volatile(addr_of_mut!(X), 0xC);
   |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

warning: `testje2` (bin "testje2") generated 1 warning
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s

I get the warning for X, and following the mentioned link, I think I understand the reasoning why you wouldn't want to allow &mut on a static. And the suggested change does get rid of the warning.
My question is, why does the compiler complain about &mut X, but not about &mut Y[0]? Isn't this essentially the same situation?
I expected the compiler to complain about both &mut references since they both refer to a global static.

It's a limitation of the current lint, which I think according to #123060 is intended to be resolved (the reference in this case is "hidden" behind the sugared call to Index::index_mut).
